# Rails 4 with CanCan: unknown attribute error after including load_and_authorize_resource

Tags: cancan, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm working in Rails 4 and have gotten CanCan to work well with instructions from [this issue](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/835#issuecomment-18663815), *except* for one use case that I think might be relatively common.

I have a `Comment` model, which `has_many :comments, through: :replies` for nested comments. All of this is working well, until I add `load_and_authorize_resource` to my comments controller. The problem seems to stem from a hidden field sending an optional `:parent_comment_id` attribute to my create action.

I've permitted this attribute via strong parameters:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :parent_comment_id, :post_id, :comment_id, :user_id)
end
```

So that I can create the association if a `:parent_comment_id` is included:

```
if comment_params[:parent_comment_id] != nil
  Reply.create({:parent_comment_id => comment_params[:parent_comment_id], :comment_id => @comment.id})
end
```

But once I add `load_and_authorize_resource`, I get an unknown attribute error for `:parent_comment_id`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution came to me in my sleep. Here's what I did to solve the problem:

The only reason `comment_params` wasn't normally having a problem on create, was because I was excluding the extra `:parent_comment_id` parameter, like this:

```
@comment = post.comment.create(comment_params.except(:parent_comment_id))
```

When CanCan used the `comment_params` method however, it did no such sanitation. Hence, the problem. It would have been messy to add that sanitation to CanCan on a per-controller basis, so I did what I should have done all along and instead of passing the `:parent_comment_id` inside `:comment`, I used `hidden_field_tag` to pass it outside of `:comment` and accessed it through plain, old `params`.

I hope this helps someone else who makes a similar mistake!